# How to deploy a tensorflow model in Heroku, within the free slug size available of 500MiB?

Tags: python, tensorflow, heroku

I have a Convolutional Neural Network model made in tensorflow 2.6. I wish to deploy it in free, Heroku plan. But Heroku free plan, only allows a maximum slug size of 500MiB. Is there any way I can host the model in the Heroku free plan?

My end goal is to build an API, which when passed with an image in base64 format, returns a label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

Use `tensorflow-cpu`.

`tensorflow-cpu` is much smaller than `tensorflow` and can fit into the maximum permissible size of Heroku for free, which is 500MiB.